# Sql reader is reading null row?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-2.0

I have a table in SQL which literally got no rows but one that says null(which I guess is by default) now if I read it, it goes through reader at least once, here is what I am trying to do.

```
            int Count = 0;

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Exists", conn);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Url", URL));
            SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();


            if (rdr1.Read())
            {
                Count++;
            }
```

how can I check if Rdr row is null and dont do Counter

**Edit**

Stored Procedure (I am not allowed to make changes to it)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Exists]
(
    @Url varchar(255)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rows FROM Instances 
WHERE Url = @Url
```

Comment: A row that contains nulls **is still a row**. There is no concept of a null row, btw; just a row that may have null values.

Comment: Please do: `select count(1) from YourTable` - that will tell you whether it has rows or not. Also, even if there are no rows, a sproc could still incorrectly return a row. Can you show the sproc?

Comment: K... That SP will always return exactly one row. Zero still counts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using reader why dont you just use `ExecuteScaler()`? that is better option for retrieving a single value from database.

In case, there is specific requirement to use reader then you will need to check for

```
if( reader.Read() ==true && reader[0] !=DBNull.Value)
{
count++;
}
```

Here is, how you may use ExecuteScalar: In case, nothing found in database then it will return 0.

```
             int Count = 0;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection ( " Your ConnectionString" ))
            {

                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand ( "Exists", conn ))
                {

                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@Url", URL ) );

                    conn.Open ();

                    if( Convert.ToInt32 ( cmd1.ExecuteScalar () ) > 0 )
                    {
                        Count +=1;
                    }
                    conn.Dispose ();

                }
            }
```

if there is not specific requirement to use `Count+=1;` then following lines will serve batter

```
Count = Convert.ToInt32 ( cmd1.ExecuteScalar () );
```

Answer (score 3):

If the reader is reporting `true` from `Read()`, then your stored procedure is definitely returning a row (or rows).

If you call the SP directly (SSMS etc), that will quickly tell you whether a row is returned. A row with a null in every column **is still a row**. Two options:

- fix the SP such that it doesn't return rows incorrectly (I'm guessing it is selecting into variables. And then selecting the variables: that will always yield a row)
- change the reader code to ignore impossible data

For example. If the first column must be non-null for a "real" row, then simply:

```
if(!reader.IsDBNull(0)) Count++;
```

Which ignores the row if the first cell is null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DBNull.Value` or [IsDBNull(column_ordinal)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) method to test the value of a specific column is null or not.

Comment: am not sure, how I will gonna use it tho :s

Answer (score 1):

**First** - You are missing the `Memory Management`. The code should be like below...

```
int Count = 0;
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Exists", conn))
{
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Url", URL));
    using (SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (rdr1.Read())
        {
            Count++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

`Count` will always return something, either 0 record or more then 0. So, you will always receive a row which will have count of rows for a particular URL.